# Smooth out rounded window corners

Tags: windows, delphi

HI

I've created a window with rounded edges using the windows API calls CreateRoundRgn and SetWindowRgn however the rounded corners are not as smooth as say a rounded rectangle drawn with GDI+.  Is there anyway to smooth out the window corners?

```
procedure TPBSDashboardPanel.DefineWindowRegion;
var
  WindowRegion: HRGN;
begin
  if Assigned(Parent) then
  begin
    WindowRegion := CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 20, 20);

    SetWindowRgn(Handle, WindowRegion, True);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use a bitmap with alpha transparency to simulate the anti-aliasing in addition to a slightly bigger rounded region for allowing Windows to do hit-testing.

The problem here is that the Win32 GDI uses regions for hit-testing so when drawn every point in a region has integer logical unit coordinates, so that when hit-tested it can be known to be either outside or inside the region.

God bless

PS: AFAIK there is no way of defining the actual region used by a window which would make the windows borders to be rendered with anti-aliasing, and Win32 only supports aliased windows. The WDM in Windows 7 blurs the borders but I think this is the shadow and not the actual region which is drawn blurred.

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to draw a themed rectangle, check [this link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773298%28VS.85%29.aspx)
To render (semi) transparent bitmap, what (I guess) would be your aim, check out [this function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183351)
For usage of both functions, let me know or inspire yourself using Google.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on this, but I do know that GDI+ supports anti-aliasing, whereas GDI does not. Without anti-aliasing, rounded corners will not look smooth.