# Delphi Borderless and Captionless Application

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am willing to designed one Application in Delphi XE2 Borderlessly and Captionlessly by using the following code :

```
  BorderIcons = []
  BorderStyle = bsNone
```

But the problem is that there is no Menu on Right Click on the Application on Taskbar just like in the above image. Then I have tried the following codes on FormShow event, but there is also another problem. One Border is created on Left side and Left-Botton side. The codes are :

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  r: TRect;
begin
  r := ClientRect;
  OffsetRect(r, 0, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION));
  OffsetRect(r, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFRAME));
  SetWindowRgn(Handle,
  CreateRectRgn(
  r.Left, r.Top,
  ClientWidth + r.Left, ClientHeight + r.Top), True);

end;
```

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901965/can-you-make-a-borderless-application-main-window-in-windows-without-ws-popup-s

Comment: Reason that the above is a duplicate is because what is happening inside the TForm component, is that when you set the `BorderStyle=bsNone`, you also get (for free!) the style WS_POPUP set up. The linked duplicate actually shows a really low level way you can get your window recognized as a top-level Window, even though it is chromeless (borderless). Quote: " In short, borderless forms using BorderStyle=bsNone (dwStyle=WS_POPUP) block all Windows functionality that usually applies to main windows of applications, and all the solutions below solve part of it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do what [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) says and/or also take a look at:
[SetWindowRgn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425595/smooth-out-rounded-window-corners) API.

If you use just the SetWindowRgn you don't have to  remove the TForm's border, just make a rectangle that starts below it.

Comment: OP is currently already doing this, and (it seems) perhaps it doesn't do what the OP wants.

Comment: @user Since you seemed to reject this option in the question, could you explain how it solves the problem? It seems more complex than just adding `WS_SYSMENU` into the window style as Sertac and myself suggested.

Comment: Wow, the OP accepted this answer, which contradicts the text in their question.  Downvoting this question as useless.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>The simple solution is not to remove the system menu in the first place. Note that the system menu is the official name for the menu that is missing in your app.</strike>

Make your .dfm file look like this:

```
BorderIcons = [biSystemMenu]
BorderStyle = bsNone
```

Get rid of that `FormShow` code–it's not needed.

OK, it looks like a stray bit of code from my experimentation was confounding me. Here's what works.

Do exactly what you originally did in your .dfm form:

```
BorderIcons = []
BorderStyle = bsNone
```

Then add back the system menu using `CreateParams`:

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
protected
  procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
end;
...
procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.Style := Params.Style or WS_SYSMENU;
end;
```

Comment: I don't see any difference in XE2 in the behaviour of the launched application whether the BorderIcons is [] or [biSystemMenu].  What was I supposed to see different in Win7? The taskbar icon still exists and still has exactly 'Project.exe' and "Close window" and "Pin to taskbar", those three items only, even with the options above set.

Comment: @Warren That's the win 7 taskbar. Hover mouse over taskbar button. Then right click the aero preview. Then you see the system menu. XP and Vista taskbars showed system menu more readily if I recall.

Comment: I can't make this work, I don't see the system menu on the task thumb and it does not show up with Alt+Space either.

Comment: @Sertac I looked again at my example project and I still had a stray piece of experimentation in the code. The `CreateParams` call to add back `WS_SYSMENU`.

Comment: Just wanted to add here that this works great it you use:   Application.Minimize; to minimize your window but doesn't work well if you use WindowState := wsMinimized; Interesting thing is that you can't use Application.Minimize OnMouseDown but you have to use it OnClick. No such problems with WindowState.

Answer (score 5):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE, 
      WS_POPUP or WS_CLIPSIBLINGS or WS_CLIPCHILDREN or WS_SYSMENU);
  SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT or WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
end;
```

You don't need the code in the OnShow handler with this solution.

The above code can be called any time (not just in `OnCreate`), it can be used to alter the behavior of a running form for instance (just include `WS_VISIBLE` to window styles if the form is already visible).

If you want the behavior to be in effect for the life time of the form, it's better to set the flags in an overriden `CreateParams` (where form styles are applied by VCL). This will also take possible recreation of the form into account. Don't set any form property from the OI for this solution, all of the flags are explicitly set in the code:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;

..

procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.Style := WS_POPUP or WS_CLIPSIBLINGS or WS_CLIPCHILDREN or WS_SYSMENU;
  Params.ExStyle := WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
end;
```

Comment: +1 But isn't this needed in `CreateParams` in case the handle gets recreated? And isn't it better to augment the styles by simply including `WS_SYSMENU` with an `or` rather than setting all styles?

Comment: @David - (1) I don't know OP's level of expertise, I thought it's better to start simple.. OP can figure out a way or ask a question if the form is getting recreated :).  (2) Dunno, the flags are what it should amount to by default.

Comment: (1) That's just storing up a nasty surprise at some point in the future I suspect. (2) I'm sure you are correct.

Comment: Agreed.  Please update this to use CreateParams, think of the future and the general usefulness of this question to EVERYBODY, not just if this answer helps the OP today.

Comment: @Warren - I hope it's a bit better now. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can have a window that appears not to have a caption bar, or a standard caption, by simply taking over the painting of the entire window:

Create a new empty application. Use this code for your form:

```
unit ncUnit1;

interface

// XE2 uses clause
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,      
  Vcl.Graphics,   Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;
// If you're not using XE2 take out the prefixes (WinApi, Vcl, System, etc)

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  protected
    procedure WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint); message WM_NCPAINT;
    procedure SolidColorNcPaint(solidColor,frameColor:TColor);
    procedure Resizing(State: TWindowState); override;


  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint);
begin
  SolidColorNcPaint(clBtnFace,clBtnFace);
end;

procedure TForm1.Resizing(State: TWindowState);
begin
  inherited;
  PostMessage(Self.Handle,WM_NCPAINT,0,0); {force initial paint}
end;

procedure TForm1.SolidColorNcPaint(solidColor,frameColor:TColor);
var
 aBorder:Integer;
 ahdc : HDC;
begin
 aBorder := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZEFRAME);
 canvas.Lock;
 ahdc := GetWindowDC(Handle);
 canvas.Handle := ahdc;
 ExcludeClipRect(canvas.Handle, aBorder, 0, Width-aBorder, Height - aBorder) ;
 Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
 Canvas.Brush.Color := frameColor;
 Canvas.Pen.Color := solidColor;
 Canvas.Rectangle( 0,0, Width,Height);
 ReleaseDC(Self.Handle, ahdc);
 canvas.Handle := 0;
 canvas.Unlock;
end;


end.
```

What you see above is only enough code to redraw a solid color  over the non-client area of the window, not to remove it completely. Depending on the style of custom window you want, you should render whatever you want on the form.  If you don't want a Close button then remove the close button, and if you do not want the resizing behaviour, remove the resizing behaviour.  If you set the `FormStyle=fsDialog` plus the above code, you would get a window that has a complete custom drawn title area (which you can put whatever you want into).  If you actually don't want the title area to exist at all, you can modify the above code to achieve that too.

Comment: I have tried your procedure. I form style is bs_none the problem is the same else on wright clicking on the application on taskbar the full Form is is recreated with caption and border

Comment: I did not tell you to set the form style to bsNone. I said to change it to fsDialog.