# How to create a form with transparent round corners?

Tags: forms, delphi, transparency

I tried the **TransparentColor/TransparentColorValue** methode but its not working very well, there is still some extra unwanted pixels of the background color in the corners, see:
[image: Unwanted extra pixels]

The entire background of the app is a picture (Timage) so I want to hide completely the background of the form, How can I do that ?

Comment: The same as has been [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4425595/960757)?

Comment: Are you talking about [`Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.GlassFrame`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.GlassFrame)?

Comment: Double check your image. The pixels in the corner do not match the `TransparentColorValue` *exactly*, which is why they are not transparent

Comment: I agree with Remy's suggestion. Also while you are at it make sure that the program you use for editing images isn't doing any edge smoothing using Anti-Aliasing or similar algorithms as they change edge pixels slightly so that edges look more smooth. And since this pixels no longer match your transparent color exactly they will be seen on your picture as their rendering isn't skipped as it is with all those pixels that do match your transparent color.

Comment: @Sami i don't know what is it, i searched a little i found "The property is only available for Windows Vista or Windows 7 with Aero. Otherwise, the Glass Frame is ignored" so i think i shouldn't use it, thank you anyway

Comment: @RemyLebeau the image is perfect, the pixels are of the form not the image

Comment: @SilverWarior i used Photoshop, is XD will be better ?

Comment: @Clay the pixels in question DO appear to be part of the image, not the Form. The image appears to have darker pixels against the rounded edges. So either fix those pixels, or else you will have to use the Win32 [`SetWindowRgn()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowrgn) API instead of the `TransparentColorValue` property to define the desired shape of the Form to make the rounding mask off those unwanted pixels

Comment: If you used Photoshop to create the image, then photoshop by default (you can disable it) will anti-alias the edges, taking them off the color key.  There are different functions you can use to make the form truly transparent with per-pixel alpha blending, here's a detailed article : http://www.blichmann.de/en/programming/delphi/translucency/index.html