# How to make RoundRectRgn smoother?

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

```
HRGN hRgn1 = CreateRoundRectRgn(0,0,400,400,50,50); 
SetWindowRgn(hWnd, hRgn1, TRUE);
```

If I use this function directly, the window corners have a lot of aliasing, how Do I make it look smoother?

Or, it will need an image, but I wanted to realize it with the `WindowDC(HBITMAP)`.

Comment: Use gdiplus. as it supports anti-aliasing. It doesn't have a native RoundRect function but you can get the same effect using a path. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67052759/c-gdi-how-to-draw-rectangle-with-border-radius

Comment: I know that gdiplus could anti-aliasing,but how could I  clip the window?

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425595/smooth-out-rounded-window-corners

Comment: Regions cannot be anti-aliased, only a monitor with a higher dpi could make it look better.  One of the reasons why SetWindowRgn() is rarely used.

Comment: Sorry I missed that you wanted it for a window region. You can't do it. Use `UpdateLayeredWindow()` instead.

Comment: Could you give me a UpdateLayeredWindow() example with round rect ergion?thank you!

Comment: Layered windows support per-pixel alpha transparency. You'll have to render the corner radius using a method that supports anti-aliasing. Since GDI doesn't you'll have to consider using another library, like GDI+.

Comment: I have already made an GDI+ rounded rect function,but how to change it into region?

Comment: @末影小末EnderMo "*how to change it into region?*" - you don't, that is the whole point. You wouldn't use a region *at all* in this situation. A Layered window has its own native transparency/translucency, so there is no need for a region. Simply create the window using a bitmap that has an alpha channel to mask out the corner pixels you don't want rendered opaguely.

Comment: I already make a function to change a gdi bitmap to function,but it need to use gdi+ for the anti-aliasing now,that is the problem